# Неправильное значение Sound.length

Tags: flash, actionscript

Вызываю с созданного объекта Sound поле length и мне постоянно возвращает только 0:

```
var snd:Sound = new Sound(new URLRequest("0.mp3"));
var num:Number = snd.length;
```

Что может быть не так?

Comment: Небось адрес неверно задан.. наверняка 0.mp3 не является верным URL-адресом

Comment: Ничего такого не пишет.

Comment: Задал полный путь и ничего не поменялось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

возможно для потокового формата это свойство не вернет корректное значение

попробуйте через получение события id3

> Отправляется объектом Sound, если для
> звука в формате MP3 доступны данные
> ID3.

Comment: Я использую NetStream. Файл берется с сервера Red5 по http. Как в этом случае можно получить длину?

Comment: То есть событие ID3 не всплывает ?

Comment: Нет.

Comment: Мне это нужно для прогресса воспроизведения и перехода по треку.

Comment: Уверен, что к моменту чтения length мп3 весь приехал ?

Comment: а в этом экземпляре мп3 есть ID3 ? winamp к примеру его видит ?

Comment: ID3 есть. Его AIMP3 видет

Answer (score 0):

и лучше подпишитесь на события с ошибками, может там действительно недоступен файл

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("0.mp3");
var soundFactory:Sound = new Sound();
soundFactory.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,    completeHandler);
soundFactory.addEventListener(Event.ID3, id3Handler);
soundFactory.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
soundFactory.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
soundFactory.load(request);
song = soundFactory.play();
```